# Пул процессов в multiprocessor. Подвисания

Tags: python

Есть функция:

```
def checker(syn_list):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(PROCESS_COUNT, maxtasksperchild=10)
    async_result = pool.map_async(check_syn, syn_list)
    results = async_result.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results
```

check_syn проверяет урл (там делается urllib2.urlopen() без таймаута) и возвращает код ответа либо ошибку из исключений.

Некоторые урлы битые (какие именно - до проверки непонятно), ответ от сервера не приходит вообще, исключение не генерится. Процессы подвисают, со временем новые просто перестают создаваться.

Как этого подвисания избежать?

P.S.: Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Решено.

Сам продуплил, нужно было задать приемлемый таймаут для urlopen()

С таймаутом генерится исключение socket.timeout (только надо сделать import socket), которое потом перехватывается и обрабатывается.